# NetworkX isomorphic connected components

Tags: python, graph, networkx, isomorphism

I am solving a specific problem, I would appreciate any suggestions you had for this problem, its trivial but I am not sure if this is the best way to solve this problem.

**The Problem**: Given a graph `G`, lets say you get a set of connected component subgraphs `{C_1, C_2, ....., C_N}`. Now partition the aforementioned set into `K` subsets such that every element in the subset are isomorphic with each-other. You can have atmost `N` subsets.

**The Solution**:

1. Run a find connected sugraphs. This will return all the connected components as graphs.
2. Partition this connected components subgraphs based on  number of nodes (Which should be fine in our case). **Optional**
3. For the subgraphs. Run the following:

   - Initialize a dictionary with the following. A random node as the key and a singleton set containing the graph itself as its value and add remaining nodes to a `deque`.
   - For the remaining nodes:

     - pop the element in the front of the deque. If there's  an isomorphism match add that graph to the dictionary of subgraph, else push the element to its back.
     - Once there's absolute certainity that we have reached a cycle. I.e. we are scanning the same element which we pushed to the back of the queue. This node's cycle is done. Pop the front of the queue and add the `<graph:set([graph])>` entry to the dictionary mentioned before. Repeat until there are elements left in the queue.

**Can this be further otpimized?**

```py
import networkx as nx
nx_graph = nx.Graph()
edges = [
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 4),
    (5, 6),
    (6, 7),
    (7, 8),
    (9, 10),
    (10, 11),
    (10, 12)
]
for edge in edges:
    nx_graph.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
    
nx.draw(nx_graph, pos=nx.spring_layout(nx_graph), node_color='#1ab2c3', with_labels=True)
```

Graph:

[image]

```py
from collections import deque

def paritition_isomorphic_subgraphs(graph):
    subgraphs_gen = (graph.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(graph))
    subgraphs_list = list(subgraphs_gen)

    graph_queue = deque(subgraphs_list)

    graph_of_interest = graph_queue.popleft()
    isomprohic_elements = {
        graph_of_interest: set([graph_of_interest])
    }

    last_element_popped = None
    count = 0
    first_mismatch = None

    while graph_queue:
        if graph_queue[0] == first_mismatch:
            count = 0
            graph_of_interest = graph_queue.popleft()
            isomprohic_elements[graph_of_interest] = set([graph_of_interest])
        if graph_queue:
            graph = graph_queue.popleft()
            if nx.is_isomorphic(graph_of_interest, graph):
                isomprohic_elements[graph_of_interest].add(graph)
            else:
                if count == 0:
                    first_mismatch = graph
                graph_queue.append(graph)
                count += 1
    return list(isomprohic_elements.values())
```